# How to decode b"\x80" in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, stdout

I want to decode `b"\x80"` in python (I want to receive `"\x80"`).
When I tried `b"\x80".decode("utf-8")`, it gives me UnicodeDecodeError.
But when I tried just `"\x80"`, it gives me what I expected.
Why it's happened and how to get what I expect?

Comment: What exactly do you expect? A string with four characters: backslash "ex" 8 0? That's not what `b"\x80"` represents…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the latin-1 encoding to get the result you want.

```
>>> b"\x80".decode('latin-1')
'\x80'
```

This is a 8-bit encoding that covers `\x00` to `\xff`. The first 256 code points of Unicode are based on latin-1 (aka ISO/IEC 8859-1)

You can also use encoding `unicode_escape`, which even works with higher unicode escape codes such as `b"\u0080"` and `b"\U00000080"`.

```
>>> b"\u0080".decode('unicode_escape')
'\x80'
```